# Automated tools fot testing Software Architecture

Tags: application-software-testing, test-architecture, qa-architect

Are there any tools (paid or open-source) to validate web applications' software architecture (.NET technology) to measure aspects like cohesion and coupling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NDepend](https://www.ndepend.com/) is the .NET equivalent of JDepend.
You can find more info about the metrics [here](https://www.ndepend.com/features/code-quality#Metrics).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Selenium**

Selenium is one of the most popular automation tool. It is a free and open-source device with a few instructional exercises and a functioning local area.

**Watir**

Watir represents Web Application Testing In Ruby. It is a free and open-source program automation tool. It upholds ruby language as it were.

**Katalon Studio**

Katalon Studio is a free automation tool utilizing which we can robotize sites, APIs – SOAP and Rest just as portable applications.

**QTP** or **UFT**

Quick Test Professional(QTP) is a paid useful test automation tool  given by Hewlett Packard. It upholds prearranging in VB script and can computerize both web and windows applications.

**TestComplete**

TestComplete is a paid GUI automation tool given by Smartbear. It upholds both record and playback also as scripting and can automated Web, Mobile, and Desktop applications.

Comment: Welcome to SQA Stack Exchange. You might want to review the accepted answer and the original question - they are asking for tools to analyze the structure of the code they're testing, not tools for UI automation.